Python string: extract duplicated and randomly merged substring
Example of duplicated and merged string:
16.01068.0%0 8p%.a .p .a.

Desired substring to be extracted:
16.008% p.a.

Fuller example:
CCoonnttiinnggeenntt CCoouuppoonn 16.01068.0%0 8p%.a .p (.Ma.o (nMtholyn)thly)

Desired substring:
Contingent Coupon 16.008% p.a. (Monthly)

My problem is when the original substring already has duplicate characters (like the two 0s in 16.008), my current function sometimes retains the wrong duplicate character (giving the incorrect result 16.080).

what you need is to learn how to extract data from a pdf correctly. you're just wasting your time trying to work around that issue

I've rolled back your edit. Please do not vandalize the post after it's been answered. Please read: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/332820/what-to-do-when-someone-answers-dont-be-a-chameleon-dont-be-a-vandal

You can think of the phenomenon as a duplicating string trailing behind the main string by some number of characters. Since the duplicating string at index i should always match the main string at index i, you can use this characteristic as a way to determine if an incoming character belongs to the duplicating string or the main string. To handle cases where the correct string has two of the same consecutive characters and the second of them is encountered, you can use a backtracking algorithm to find a path that leads to a matching duplicate string.
Note that the duplicating characters are most likely a result of an emulation of a bold font, but since there's nothing visible in duplicating spaces they're unfortunately identified by the PDF scanner as one space. As a workaround you can artificially replace each space in the input with two spaces, and then replace any two consecutive spaces with one space for output. Note also that your input string may be missing a trailing space since the scanner is unable to identity one without a visible boundary, you can artificially append a trailing space to the input and strip trailing spaces afterwards:
def dedupe(string):
    def _dedupe(pos, dupe):
        if pos == size:
            return dupe == half
        char = string[pos]
        if (dupe < len(output) and output[dupe] == char and
                _dedupe(pos + 1, dupe + 1)):
            return True
        output.append(char)
        if _dedupe(pos + 1, dupe):
            return True
        output.pop()

    string = (string + ' ').replace(' ', '  ')
    size = len(string)
    half = size // 2
    output = []
    if _dedupe(0, 0):
        return ''.join(output).replace('  ', ' ').rstrip()
    raise ValueError('No matching duplicate found.')

so that:
print(dedupe(
"CCoonnttiinnggeenntt CCoouuppoonn 16.01068.0%0 8p%.a .p (.Ma.o (nMtholyn)thly)"
))

outputs:
Contingent Coupon 16.008% p.a. (Monthly)

Demo here

I see. The duplicating characters are most likely a result of an emulation of a bold font, but since there's nothing visible in duplicating spaces they're unfortunately identified by the scanner as one space.

Yes, I believe so.

Well I've updated my answer with a workaround then.

I've updated the answer with a backtracking algorithm then.

Why do you add an extra space at the end of the string?

You're welcome. As noted in the updated answer, your input appears to be missing a trailing space presumably because the scanner is unable to identity one without a visible boundary, so as a workaround we can add a trailing space to the input and strip trailing spaces afterwards.

blhsing:  I'm wondering if you can help again.  Very similar problem as before, but instead of one string being shuffled together with its duplicate, this time it's two different strings randomly shuffled together and we know one of the strings.  Example merged string: "UDpigsitidael P Paayrmticeipnattion 1x (6U0n%capped)", the one known string: "Upside Participation  1x (Uncapped)", desired second string: "Digital Payment 60%".  As in the previous problem, backtracking will be required.  I've tried and failed so far.  Thank you in advance.

Yes, but please post this as a new question since the new constraint makes the question rather different.

Yes, I'll create a new post for this question.
